# Convert formula to a comment

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

When programming, I often comment code out whilst I'm debugging.

I have a formula, which works fine, but I want to comment it out as I don't need it at the moment but will do in a few weeks time.

Whilst I could easily copy this formula to another place or make the text white to blend in with background, is there a way to disable the formula from working or convert it into a comment, so the formula remains in place but never executes and therefore shows a blank cell.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a single quote at the beginning of the cell so:

```
 =SUM(A:A)
```

becomes

```
 '=SUM(A:A)
```

This effectively says "this cell is text, don't do anything to it".

Comment: Note that this overrides all number formatting. So even if it is a bare number (instead of a formula) it will be treated as "text". Now: to make it NOT SHOW a trick is needed e.g. **`=LEFT("`*your formula here*`";0)`**  (note `;` OR `,` before the last `0` depends on the current locale settings).

Comment: I suppose another way would be to use conditional formatting to make cells that begin with `'=` white text on white background.